# setting child view controller emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
{{#each posts}}
  {{view App.PostView controller=App.PostController}}
{{/each}}
```

but this is always getting parentView controller instead of PostController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss putting App.PostController between double quotes. The controller have to be an instance, not a class here. So you have to instantiate App.PostController in your js code beafore using it in the template.